# Gamma adjustment with per screen control in menubar for macOS?

Tags: macos, display

I need to sometimes adjust gamma very quickly on a per monitor basis (I have multiple displays) sometimes and would like to find a menubar app to accomplish this perhaps similar to [Desktop Dimmer](https://github.com/sidneys/desktop-dimmer) for macOS.

[image: example]

This looks like it could be pretty close, but perhaps not as clean, simple (or as affordable) as I'd like: [Gamma Control](https://apps.apple.com/ca/app/gamma-control/id1250521285?l=en)